# Filename with special characters in ADODB recorset

Tags: character, adodb

This following code bugs because the csv filename (COTPMS1_20220701.txt_01072022_01h15m20s.csv) contains a special character (a dot) in addition of the extension. Is there a way to escape this special character ? I would like indeed to avoid to copy and rename the file in other directory.

```
Sub testSpecialCharacter()

Dim cn As Object
Dim rsT As Object
Dim fullpath As String, _
    ExtendedProp As String, _
    query As String

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsT = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

fullpath = "C:\test\"
ExtendedProp = """text;HDR=NO"""

With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    .connectionstring = "Data Source=" & fullpath & ";Extended Properties=" & ExtendedProp
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open
End With

query = "SELECT * FROM [COTPMS1_20220701.txt_01072022_01h15m20s.csv]"

rsT.Open query, cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

rsT.Close
cn.Close
Set rsT = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the very same issue as my file names included spaces, dashes and underscores. I tried to figure it out by trial and error but did not get much luck. In the end, I found some comments from a JAVA post and I tried to apply it to VBA. It worked like a charm: basically all you have to do is to encapsulate your csv file name in SQUARE BRACKETS, just like a common query.
For example:

```
"SELECT * FROM " & filename*with_special+chars.csv ---> error
"SELECT * FROM [" & some_file*with_special+chars.csv & "]" ---> This works.
```

Hope this helps.